# Notation: $f(c^+)$ and $f(c^-)$

Tags: calculus, limits, notation

My lecturer often does this:
$$
\text{Let} \quad f(c^-) = \lim_{x \to c^-} f(x)  \quad \text{and} \quad f(c^+) = \lim_{x \to c^+} f(x).
$$
Is $f(c^-)$ and $f(c^+)$ standard notation for one-sided limits in calculus? Are there any alternatives that are widely used?

Comment: My teacher also uses the same notation. $$f(c^-)= lim_{x \to c^-} f(x) = lim_{h \to 0} f(c-h)$$

Comment: In my high school days of calculus the notation was $f(c+0),f(c-0)$ for right and left limit of $f$ at $c$. The notation $f(c+), f(c-) $ is also common.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you write it like 
$$
f(c^-) = \lim_{x \uparrow c} f(x) \text{ and } f(c^+) = \lim_{x \downarrow c} f(x),
$$
and it is just a way of writing the left-sided limit and the right-sided limit.

See [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-sided_limit).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise that page existed. Apparently $f(x-)$ and $f(x+)$ is used in probability theory.

Comment: That is true. If your question is therefore answered, please mark it as answered.